# JQuery: Rebind $(document).Ready()

Tags: jquery, document-ready

JQuery unbinds the `$(document).ready()` once the `document.ready()` is triggered.

```
jQuery( document ).trigger( "ready" ).unbind( "ready" );
```

I want to rebind the the `$(document).ready()` so that I can call it manually ( calling `jQuery.ready()` OR `jQuery(document).trigger("ready")`) in my helper function.

I can write a separate function and call both in document ready and the helper but I can not do that as I want to write a generic helper that can be used on any page.

Any Idea how to do it?

Comment: Using a separate function sounds like the right thing to do. Perhaps you could provide more details about why this isn't practical?

Comment: @Timir, the semantics are different, but would binding to `load` on `window` instead of `ready` on `document` be an option? The `load` event can be re-triggered later, as you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

That does not sound like a good idea, any third-party plugins may behave badly if they see a ready event more than once. There is a `jQuery.holdReady()` that you can use to make jQuery wait until you've given it the go-ahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the logic inside the `.ready()` method multiple times, simply place the logic in your own method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  myReadyFunction(); // Called when the DOM is ready
});

function myReadyFunction() { // Called when the DOM is ready & whenever you want
    //Do stuff
}
```